# WPF datagrid binding with datatable

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, datatable

I know that my datatable has data in it but I don't see it in my datagrid. here is my binding.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Name="DataGrid4" AutoGenerateColumns="TRUE" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=thisData.thisFollowUp.thisP.pData.dataTable.DefaultView}"/>
```

It is my understanding that I do not need to notify WPF when the datatable data has changed. Any Ideas what I am missing? I will add more code if it is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the `DataContext` of the enclosing container for the `DataGrid` you just need to call `ItemSource = {Binding}`. You can set the `DataContext` after you load the data in code behind. [Examples](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples)